# Files appearing twice in unity dash

Tags: 16.04, unity, unity-dash

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. This is my first time using Linux. The issue I'm having is as follows:

If I download or open some file, it appears twice in the dash even though it's single in quantity.

[image]

Please let me know why this is the case and how I can remedy this.

Edit: The doubling seems to be happening only for files I've downloaded from the web.

Thanks.

Comment: Pick a pair of duplicated icons. One at a time, right-click on the icon, and note the path to the file. Do the same for the other dup, and note the path. Are the paths similar, or different?

Comment: @heynnema, the paths are the same.

Comment: What is the path? Also, in the dash window with the dups, click on "filter results", take a screenshot, and add it to your question.

Comment: Please see my answer. Please remember to vote/accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

is the doubling temporary?

one possible reason:
to reduce fragmentation, the download manager reserves space for the complete file then downloads to a second file. Once completed, the file is moved to the reserved space and the second copy removed.

When a file is opened in an editor, a temporary recovery file is made in case of a crash.

Comment: No, this doesn't seem temporary. The doubles do not go away, even if I restart my computer. Also, this doubling only seems to be happening for files I've downloaded from the web, so you might be right. Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do this...

- select `System Settings`
- select `Security & Privacy`
- select `Files & Applications` tab
- click on `Clear Usage Data`
- in the time dialog that appears, select an appropriate time frame
- click `OK`
- click `YES`

reference: https://www.ostechnix.com/clear-unity-dash-search-history-ubuntu/